# Converting word2vec output into dataframe for sklearn

Tags: python, scikit-learn, nlp, gensim, word2vec

I am attempting to use [gensim's word2vec](https://radimrehurek.com/gensim/models/word2vec.html) to transform a column of a pandas dataframe into a vector that I can pass to a [`sklearn` classifier](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/supervised_learning.html) to make a prediction.

I understand that I need to average the vectors for each row. I have tried [following this guide](https://machinelearningmastery.com/develop-word-embeddings-python-gensim/) but I am stuck, as I am getting models back but I don't think I can access the underlying embeddings to find the averages.

Please see [a minimal, reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) below:

```
import pandas as pd, numpy as np
from gensim.models import Word2Vec
from gensim.models.doc2vec import Doc2Vec, TaggedDocument
from sklearn.feature_extraction.text import CountVectorizer

temp_df = pd.DataFrame.from_dict({'ID': [1,2,3,4,5], 'ContData': [np.random.randint(1, 10 + 1)]*5, 
                                'Text': ['Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet', 'consectetur adipiscing elit.', 'Sed elementum ultricies varius.',
                                         'Nunc vel risus sed ligula ultrices maximus id qui', 'Pellentesque pellentesque sodales purus,'],
                                'Class': [1,0,1,0,1]})
temp_df['text_lists'] = [x.split(' ') for x in temp_df['Text']]

w2v_model = Word2Vec(temp_df['text_lists'].values, min_count=1)

cv = CountVectorizer()
count_model = pd.DataFrame(data=cv.fit_transform(temp_df['Text']).todense(), columns=list(cv.get_feature_names_out()))
```

Using [`sklearn's CountVectorizer`](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.feature_extraction.text.CountVectorizer.html), I am able to get a simple frequency representation that I can pass to a classifier. How can I get that same format using Word2vec?

This toy example produces:

```
adipiscing  amet    consectetur dolor   elementum   elit    id  ipsum   ligula  lorem   ... purus   qui risus   sed sit sodales ultrices    ultricies   varius  vel
0   0   1   0   1   0   0   0   1   0   1   ... 0   0   0   0   1   0   0   0   0   0
1   1   0   1   0   0   1   0   0   0   0   ... 0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0
2   0   0   0   0   1   0   0   0   0   0   ... 0   0   0   1   0   0   0   1   1   0
3   0   0   0   0   0   0   1   0   1   0   ... 0   1   1   1   0   0   1   0   0   1
4   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   ... 1   0   0   0   0   1   0   0   0   0
```

While this runs without error, I cannot access the embedding that I can pass with this current format. I would like to produce the same format, with the exception of instead of there being counts, its the `word2vec` value embeddings

Answer (score 2, accepted):

While yo might not be able to help it if your original data comes from a Pandas `DataFrame`, neither Gensim nor Scikit-Learn work with `DataFrame`-style data natively. Rather, they tend to use raw `numpy` arrays, or base Python datastructures like `list`s or iterable sequences.

Trying to shoehorn interim raw vectors into the Pandas style of data structure tends to add code complication & wasteful overhead.

That's especially true if the vectors are dense vectors, where essentially all of a smaller-number of dimensions are nonzero, as in word2vec-like algorthms. But that's also true if the vectors are the kinds of sparse vectors, with a giant number of dimensions, but most dimensions 0, that come from `CountVectorizer` and various "bag-of-words"-style text models.

So first, I'd recommend *against* putting the raw outputs of `Word2Vec` or `CountVectorizer`, which are usually interim representations on the way to completing some other task, into a `DataFrame`.

If you want to have the final assigned-labels in the `DataFrame`, for analysis or reporting in the Pandas style, only add those final outputs in the end. But to understand the interim vector representations, and then to pass them to things like Scikit-Learn classifiers in the formats those classes expect, keep those vectors (and inspect them yourself for clarity) in the their raw `numpy` vector formats.

In particular, after `Word2Vec` runs (with the parameters you've shown), there'll be a 100-dimensional vector *per word*. Not per multi-word text. And the 100-dimensions have no names other than their indexes 0 to 99.

And unlike the dimensions of the `CountVectorizer` representation, which are counts of individual words, each dimension of the "dense embedding" will be some floating-point decimal value that has no clear or specific interpretation alone: it's only directions/neighborhoods in the whole space, shearing across many dimensions, that vaguely correspond with useful or human-nameable concepts.

If you want to turn the per-word 100-dimensional vectors into vectors for a multi-word text, there are many potential ways to do so – but one simple choice is to simply average together the N word-vectors into 1 summary vector. Gensim's class holding the word-vectors inside the `Word2Vec` model, `KeyedVectors`, has a [`.get_mean_vector()` method](https://radimrehurek.com/gensim/models/keyedvectors.html#gensim.models.keyedvectors.KeyedVectors.get_mean_vector) that can help. For example:

```py
texts_as_wordlists = [x.split(' ') for x in temp_df['Text']]
text_vectors = [w2v_model.wv.get_mean_vector(wordlist) for wordlist in texts_as_wordlists]
```

There are many other potential ways to use word-vectors to model a longer text. For example, you might reweight the words before averagine. But a simple average is a reasonable first baseline approach. (Other algorithms related to word2vec, like the 'Paragraph Vector' algorihtm implemented by the `Doc2Vec` class, can also create a vector for a multi-word text, and such a vector is **not** just the average of its word-vectors.)

Two other notes on using `Word2Vec`:

- word2vec vectors only get good when trained on lots of word-usage data. Toy-sized examples trained on only hundreds, or even tens-of-thousands, of words rarely show anything useful, or anything resembling the power of this algorithm on larger data set.
- `min_count=1` is essentially always a bad idea with this algorithm. Related to the point above, the algorithm needs multiple subtly-contrasting usage examples of any word to have any chance of placing it meaningfully in the shared-coordinate space. Words with just one, or even a few, usages tend to get awful vectors not generalizable to the word's real meaning as would be evident from a larger sample of its use. And, in natural-language corpora, such few-example words are very numerous - so they wind up taking a lot of the training time, and achieving their *bad* representations actually worsens the vectors for *surrounding* words, that could be better because there are enough training examples. So, the best practice with word2vec is usually to *ignore* the rarest words – train as if they weren't even there. (The class's default is `min_count=5` for good reasons, and if that results in your model missing vectors for words you think you need, get more data showing uses of those words in real contexts, rather than lowering `min_count`.)

Comment: thank you for the answer. I appreciate all of the detail and in practice and production, I would not be using any `pd.DataFrames` to pass to classifiers, though my final results would probably be put back there. Obviously using `np.ndarrays` and in some cases where applicable `scipy.csr_matri` are much preferred given their memory usage and execution speed.

Comment: In addition, the `min_count` argument was just for the toy example. More specifically, the dataset in question is roughly ~50K samples. The text will be parsed and passed to a classification algo. For that reason, I opted for `word2vec`/`doc2vec`, would the preferred use case be `doc2vec`? Though not official, I did see a Git issue closed for < 100K samples but naively assumed ~50K would be sufficient. I know there are no arbitrary thresholds, but in your experience, are you suggesting 50K samples are not sufficient to retrieve useful output from `word2vec` (or `doc2vec` if preferred)?

Comment: Alas, there's no hard-and-fast rules. The quality of word vectors is more a function of the total word count, & number/quality of usage contexts for relevant words, than any raw count of the texts that contain the words (which might after all be few-word phrases or thousands-of-words articles.) The key is to have your own robust, automatable, improving-as-you-learn methods to evaluate how well things are going as you try alternate algorithms/data/parameters.

Comment: `Doc2Vec` may be worth trying too, as another way to convert multi-word texts to fixed-length feature vectors, especially after you've got some initial pipeline & baseline results working that you can compare it against. If your classification task is mostly one of topicality these each work well, & `Doc2Vec` properly tuned might catch some patterns a more-simple combo-of-wod-vectors doesn't. But, their inputs & model-size & internal techniques are very similar, so results unlikely to vary by big leaps.

Comment: Keep in mind both will be challenged if your classification depends on shades-of-meaning from things like grammar/negation/sarcasm/etc, as they're each (along with bag-of-words word-counts) mainly about "flat" word co-occurrences & correlations, rather than the full meanings ture language understanding would give. Often that's enough – and far faster * doable in smaller budgets – for broad classification, especially into topical bins.